# Autocad 2007 raster design loading problem

Tags: autocad, autocad-map

I try to load Autodesk raster design 2007 from this link https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad/downloads/caas/downloads/content/autodesk-raster-design-2007-object-enabler.html, after I downloaded and instaled AutoCAD, I loaded the application but without results, I have to load some .sid, .ecw file with this application.

[image]

Comment: Could it be this issue? [ECW file will not load into 2018 or 2016 Civil 3D, Raster Design or Map 3D](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad-civil-3d/troubleshooting/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/ECW-file-will-not-load-into-2018-or-2016-Civil-3D-Raster-Design-or-Map-3D.html)

Comment: It is possible to load raster files in AutoCAD, actually, I load with this but I need raster design it is more comfortable 
http://www.cadstudio.cz/download?fileID=484